# How to render view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am using rails for my application.i have generated scaffold for crud operation.
 i have scaffold for product_lists. i have page called user_dashboard.html.erb here i want to render pages from product_lists.

i have `user_dashboard.html.erb` page in `pages/` directory..i want to render index.html page from product_lists directory inside `user_dashboard.html.erb`. i have tried using render.. but its showing error
here is what i have tried

```
<div class="panel-body">      
        <%= render 'product_lists' %>
</div>
```

error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#user_dashboard
```

How can i solve this error and why is this raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a partial (starts with underscore), so you need render template. You also need the full path of the template, from the view directory:

```
<%= render template: 'product_lists/index' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if its not within the same folder you need to explicit tell the path. 
the error message is showing where rails is looking for.

```
<%= render "product_lists/index" %>
```