# Rails not rendering view in custom page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to `render` contents of `user_details\index.html.erb` in my custom page `home.html`

here is my directory structure

```
apps
|
views
├───co_owners
├───layouts
├───pages
├───shared
└───user_details
```

the `home.html.erb` page is pages directory... and `index.html.erb` pages is in `user_details` directory

i am using 
`<%= render :partial => 'user_details' %>` to `render` it on my home page... but i am getting error `ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#home`

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

As an answer in a [previous your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983070/2057388)

> It is not a partial (starts with underscore), so you need render
>   template. *You also need the full path of the template*, from the view
>   directory:

```
<%= render template: 'user_details/index' %>
```

I suggest you read [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer...  i didnt recognize that as i had mad some directory changes...